# Filter array of custom objects with an attribute and Map in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, filter, higher-order-functions

My model class is as below :

```
struct Job: Decodable, Equatable, Hashable {
   var id: Int?
   var status: String?
   var priority: String?
}
```

I have 2 array of objects(job) as :

```
 var jobModel = [Job]()
 var filteredJobModel = [Job]()
```

**Case** : `jobModel` has 5 elements. `filteredJobModel` has 2 elements( subset of `jobModel` ). In `filteredJobModel`, the value for `status` for both objects has been changed by `search` operation. 
I would like to update the `jobModel` back with `filteredJobModel`, where the object matches the `id` attribute.

Is there any way by which I can achieve this case? I would have been able to use **filter** & **map** for [String], but, I would like to know how to implement higher order functions for array of custom objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (index, job) in idsJobModel.enumerated() {
    if let match = arrFiltetered.first( where: {job.id == $0.id} ) {
     idsJobModel[index] = match
   }
}
```

Or if you prefer using map:

```
idsJobModel = idsJobModel.map {
    let myID = $0.id
    if let match = arrFiltetered.first( where: {myID == $0.id} ) {
        return match
    } else {
        return $0
    }
}
```

Either version of the code above will have `O(n²)` performance, so it will get **dramatically** slower as your arrays get larger than ≈30 elements. It would need to be tweaked to perform well on larger arrays.

Comment: Assuming the `id` value in idsJobModel is always unique (and never nil), you could improve the performance of the above by mapping the arrFiltetered array into a dictionary using the id as a key. you'd then loop through idsJobModel , do a dictionary lookup of each ID, and replace the entry in idsJobModel if found as above (dictionary lookups are almost `O(1)`, so that would improve your performance to roughly `O(n)`, a dramatic improvement.

Comment: Even if your id values are not unique you could implement a custom hash function that excludes your (changeable) status property and use the hash as your dictionary key in the above speed optimization.